# How can I add a keyboard shortcut from the command-line or by editing a file?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

On Linux Mint, I would like to **bind a shortcut key to run a command***.

[I have already achieved this using the GUI](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-the-linux-mint-cinnamon-keyboard-shortcuts-4064754), but **I need a way to define this keyboard shortcut from the command-line**, without GUI interaction**.

The keybinding should work identical to the one created through the GUI and work anywhere. In other words: not a [bash binding](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/bind.htm), which would only work when sent to that terminal window.

**Further explanation:**
* **The command it will run** is `shutter -s`. It lets me take a screenshot of an area of the screen, but that isn't relevant to the scope of this question.
** **Why I want to do this**: I run Mint on many machines/VMs, and need to be able to provision new ones quickly. To achieve this, I've scripted the installation of everything I need to do dev work.

Comment: I assume your shell is bash: do you use vi-mode or emacs-mode? You'll want to read about bash's `bind` command under [Builtin commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins), particularly the `-x` option

Comment: @glennjackman I think my question was a bit ambiguous so I've re-worded it for clarity.

Comment: I have same goal. I found in comment here https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1171 commands for Mint Cinnamon (different from Ubuntu standard), they make bindings appear in GUI but shortcuts not working...